Microsoft Excel 12 OLE in Access form connection lost after editing
I have an Access form which contains an emmbeded Microsoft Excel 12 OLE object (class: Excel.Sheet.12), named Feuilles.
When I open the form, with Form_Open I store the workbook into a variable like so:
Set wb = Feuilles.Object

I can

open the workbook into the Excel application by double clicking on the object,
edit the file into the Excel application
and then close it

The problem is: after returning to the form, I cannot access the data with my wb variable ; If y try
i = wb.Worksheets.Count

I am getting error -2147220995: Object is not connected to server
It seems that I need to "reconnect" to the object but I don't manage to do it.
I tried everything I found on Internet without success :
Feuilles.Action = 7
Feuilles.Verb = 0
Feuilles.Verb = -1
...

Thank you for your help !

Where is wb declared? In the form, where in the form? How do you "return" to the form?

It is declared in the form object in vba (outside the Form_open function). After manualy closing the Excel application, it automatically returns to the form

Try declaring the wb variable in a general module header.

"I cannot access the data with my wb variable" - what exactly does that look like?  Do you get an error?  What specific error?

Instead of caching the object in a global variable create, a way to access it in "real time" Property Get wb() As Object: Set wb =  Feuilles.Object: End Property then you can just refer to wb and skip the global.

@TimWilliams : still getting an error : -2147220995 'Object is not connected to server'

@June7 : I still get the error if I declare the variable outside the form object

Please add some context - what exactly is happening when you get that error?

I add precision into my post. Is that better ? Thank you !

Are you storing Excel file in OLEObject field?

@June7, yes it is an embedded Excel into an OLE object (it is not linked to a file outside the Access database)

I have never been able to get OLEObject field and controls to work. I recently upgraded to Access 2021. Just tried again to insert file into OLEObject field and it fails. I won't be able to help.
